# CSS Issue with ie/firefox and certain widths of Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am building a wordpress website where I want the content area to "bump out" above the slider image. I created the bump out itself, but I am having issues with the content that sits inside of it. The content does not fit into the bump on Firefox & IE. On Google Chrome, some browser width fit the content correctly, while other browser sizes dont

Here is a link to the site: `http://192.185.167.175/~laurente/belle/`

I have tried working with different margins/padding and cant seem to get it to work.

I can't post images because i do not have enough reputation, but the green boxes are supposed to sit 10px below the top of the bumpout, as I have written in my css "padding-top:10px"

If you drag the browser size in chrome, you can see what I mean

Help! Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove **margin-top: -60px;** and replace it with **top: -60px;**

That should solve your problem.

Good luck building your theme. :)

Comment: Oops, forgot the div. As @Hugo said, its the .main-outer-wrapper div.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That worked perfect! I was trying so many different combinations of padding and margins, didn't realize how simple the solution was!!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamicad,

If I understood, you just need to remove the `margin-top: -60px` from `.main-outer-wrapper`

Hope it helps.